# weird visual studio to linux results

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, parsing

I have this project where we have to convert a made up simple coding language given through a txt into a c++ language and currently I am having a problem with checking my work through linux (where it will be tested on). On the other hand Visual Studio where I wrote my code works how it should be.

From what I observed something weird is going on when I am taking each line in the text, separating each word and placing it in a vector. How I do this is by starting with an empty string, looking at each character of the line, and when I see a space or a tab or any kind of character that signifies a separator then I push back that string to a vector then make the string empty again for the next characters. So something line "STR man = bloo" turns into <"STR", "man", "=", "bloo"> and so on.

In visual studio it worked like this, but it seems like in linux.. somehow the second element seems to add a weird character which would be "man ". Its not a space or an empty line and when I tried to look at size with a format std::cout << name << ":" << size << std::endl, it couts not the right format or result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9vzL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBKO5.png)

Looking at visual Studio.

first line: "size" how many elements in that vector.

second line: is a name that I want to check if its already in a vector along with the length of that name

third line: shows all the elements in that vector (which should only show 1 since the size is 1) along with its length as well.

Looking at the linux result

-first line: "size" equals 1. Which is right

second line: the name im checking and its length, which is right

third line: is where the problem occurs. The name is 1 character greater than what it is suppose to be and instead of adding onto whats printed out, it replaces the first 3 letters instead?

fourth line: should not even happen because the size is only 1 and its a basic for loop of (int i = 0; i < size; i++)

Ive tried to use brute force and just pop back the last character of the second element causing my visual studio code to fail the tests but that still fails the conditional of if the name is = to the name in the vector (which should be true) in linux. Whatever character I add on the second element when I cout that value, such as << name << "." << endl; it seems to always go and replaces first letters of that string.

Pls help

Comment: Don't try to explain your code. Show it, in form of a [mcve].

Comment: I tried to for a while, but its impossible for me to make something this  large (a parser) with numerous conditionals to a smaller scale

Comment: Having text files in Windows and Linux sounds like problems with the line endings (which are, of course, not the same), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation

Comment: You're using a Windows file with CRLF line endings on a Unix system where the standard C library doesn't need to translate line endings. And your parser apparently doesn't treat `\r` as whitespace.

Comment: I did not know of \r but after a simple conditional for it. It fixed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay, the problem was that I was not handling  invisible characters such as \r.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).